# Deploy fabric8 with gofabric8 installer behind proxy

Tags: proxy, fabric8

I am trying to install fabric8 utils with gofabric8 installer. This is the command:

```
gofabric8 deploy -d xxxx.com
```

I am behind a proxy and I get the following error:

```
Cannot get fabric8 version to deploy: Get https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/platform/packages/fabric8-platform/maven-metadata.xml: dial tcp 151.101.20.209:443: i/o timeout
```

I have already tried setting "http_proxy", "https_proxy", "HTTP_PROXY"...even "all_proxy" which is used in gofabric8 source code.

Has anybody faced the same situation? Is there any way to pass proxy as an argument to gofabric8 installer?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest to log a ticket at gofabric8 at https://github.com/fabric8io/gofabric8

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **10.0.1.1** as one of your **DNS** address in the network preferences.

Stop all your existing local clusters by using the below command:

```
minikube stop
```

Then after restart your system and try what u need.